# Integration tests design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, integration-testing

I would like to write some integration test for my application. I wasn't able to find some relevant information with examples on this subject so I'm asking here.

Let's have a controller with a simple CRUD scenario.

There is a create method, edit method and delete method.

My question is how to design the test case.

I was thinking of two ways how to test it.

1.

- Test 1 Create item - just insert an item
- Test 2 Edit item - load the item from the first test and edit it
- Test 3 Delete item - delete the item used in Test 2 and 3.

In this case all tests are more like one big test case.

1. - Test 1 Create item - insert an item, check if it's there and delete it.
   - Test 2 Edit item - insert an item,load the item, edit it and delete the item.
   - Test 3 Delete item - insert an item and delete the item

In this case the tests looks independent but they have some repetitive parts (inserts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CRUD scenario you described, the test can be implemented with three separate database transactions and their associated assertions.

Step 1 - Insert an item

Step 2 - Assert that the item was inserted successfully

Step 3 - Edit the item

Step 4 - Assert that the item as edited successfully

Step 5 - Delete the item

Step 6 - Assert that the item was deleted successfully

Comment: So this six steps should be placed into one test(method) ?

Comment: Depending on which framework(s) you are using, you may need to put each step in a separate method to make them transactional.  For example, if you are using Java, Spring, and JUnit, you can put each step in a method and annotate it with `@Test` and `@Transactional` so that the methods/steps are executed in order during the verification phase of the build.

Answer (score 1):

CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) testing is done to ensure that the system is performing CRUD activities like Creating, Retrieving, Updating and deleting.

In CRUD scenario test cases are interdependent on each other, so to test CURD scenario you need to write or check followings -

Steps 1 - Are you able to Create or Add data ?

Steps 2 - Are you able to Read or Access the saved or inserted data ?

Steps 3 - Are you able to Deleted the data along with  its relationship.

You can also use some automation tool like Watij or Selenium.

Comment: Should I look at each of steps as a separate test or are this three steps one test ?

Comment: All test cases are different but they are interdependant.